# communication between a web app and a C app?Web service?

Tags: c, web-services, web

I am trying to develop a web application that uses some input's from a c application, I don't know how to send and receive messages between the two application.

I think web service are the solution, but i don't have a clue on the technologies that suits my needs.

could any one provide me with some information or useful tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tcp/ip connections using sockets. write socket listener at server and socket client in c, which sends some data to server using socket. This is simple example how to send something from client to server

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>

void cleanup(int sig)
{
    printf("\nCleanup on exit\n");
    exit(0);
}

int create_socket(uint16_t port)
{
    /* Used variables */
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in name;

    /* Create the socket. */
    sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Give the socket a name. */
    name.sin_family = AF_INET;
    name.sin_port = htons (port);
    name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);

    /* Connect socket */
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(name)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Connect");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return sock;
}

int send_command(int sock, char *cmd) 
{
    /* Used variables */
    char command[128];
    int ret;

    /* Null-terminate command */
    bzero(command, 128);

    /* Create command */
    sprintf(command, "%s bla bla \n", cmd);

    /* Send  */
    ret = send(sock, command, strlen(command), 0);
    if (ret < 0) return 0;
    else printf("Command: %s\n", command);

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Used variables */
    int socket, ret;

    /* Catch signals */
    signal(SIGINT, cleanup);

    /* Print usage if there is no given argument */
    if (!argv[1])  
        printf("Usage: %s <command>\n", argv[0]);

    /* Create socket with server listener port */
    socket = create_socket(5544);

    /* Send commant to server */
    ret = send_command(socket, argv[1]);

    /* Check and print status */
    if (ret) printf("Command sent\n");
    else printf("Can not send command\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I commented every line on code to be useful for you

Comment: thank you for your answer, i am going to give it a try.
Is there any way for the server to interrogate the client and then the client gives his answer?

Comment: Yes, the client can accept socket and receive data from server with accept() functions. accept() returns new socket for incoming data and you can read buffer on that socket if there will be response from server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web socket for the communication between web application and c application.
Refer https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets